Message box is shown twice
In my Qt 6.8.0 application, when the update of a row fails I show an error message and I want to put the faulty row in edit mode.
Some code:
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("mydb");
_model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db);
_model->setTable("mytable");
_model->setEditStrategy(QSqlRelationalTableModel::OnRowChange);
// ... set relations, if any
_model->select();

ui->tableView->setModel(_model);
ui->tableView->setItemDelegate(new QSqlRelationalDelegate(ui->tableView));

connect(_model, &QSqlRelationalTableModel::beforeUpdate, this, [=](int row, QSqlRecord &record)
{
    if (_model->lastError().type() == QSqlError::ConnectionError)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(ui->tableView, tr("Unable to update row"), _model->lastError().text());
        QModelIndex index = _model->index(row, 0);
        ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(index);
        ui->tableView->edit(index);
    }
});

this approach has a couple of problems. For the sake of the example let's say I pretend to update the id of a row to an already existing value.

when I finish the editing if I press "enter" nothing happens (instead if the row was correct it would lead to an immediate submit)
if the user clicks on another row the error message is shown ("UNIQUE constraint failed: table.id Unable to fetch row"), but when clicking "Ok"
the error message is shown again
the clicked row is highlighted
the faulty row is in edit mode (but the other row is still selected)

Of course this is not acceptable from a user perspective.
I found an ugly hack to reduce the problems:
QTimer::singleShot(100, this, [=]()
{
    ui->tableView->setCurrentIndex(index);
    ui->tableView->edit(index);
});

Delaying these calls allows the first click to be completed - so now the faulty row will be selected and in edit mode.
What I cannot solve (easily) is to prevent the message box to be shown twice.
Another dirty hack might be to store the row argument and show the message box only if it changes.
Is there a more elegant way to fix the above issues?

beforeUpdate, as the name implies, is emitted before the update takes place in the database and that most likely explains why the UNIQUE constraint error caused by step 1. of your description only pops up at step 2.; whatever happens at 3. is probably caused by the same logic error (and the lack of a call to reverRow when encountering an error, to avoid the model submitting an invalid change again) but at this point, it is hard to figure out without a complete MRE.
